# Common File Upload for all controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, jquery-file-upload

I am building an e-commerce application in Laravel 5.6. I have so many file uploads like slider,Banner,Product images etc. All of them are ajax file uploading. Every file is uploaded to **storage/app/{respective folders}**.

After uploading, file informations are stored to **uploaded_files** mysql table. Table structure is like,

```
-------------------------
uploaded_files
-------------------------
ID
Path
file_code (Unique code for each file)
filename
extension
file_width
file_height
--------------------------
```

This **file_code** is used in other tables to reference that particular file.

**Upload Controller**:

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{

 public function index(UploadFilesRequest $request)
 {
    $dir = "slider";
    if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()) {

        $file = $request->file('image');

        // path to upload file
        $path = $dir.'/'.date('Y/m');

        // new filename for uploaded files
        $name =str_slug(pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME).'-'.base_convert(time(),10,30), '-');
        $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = $name.'.'.$extension;

        $newpath = $request->image->storeAs($path, $filename );

    }
 }
}
```

I want to use this controller method from other controllers (slider controller, product controller etc). Also **$dir** (uploads directory) and **validation rules** changes with each controllers. So how can i do that?.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Make it into a Trait or a dedicated class bound to the application container, which would resolve with the $dir and validation rules per controller.

Comment: am a newbie to laravel. How can i use traits. Any reference link ?

Comment: Traits are a PHP feature, have a look at the docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php